# Maths help with exponentials

Tags: math, exponential

Evaluate

(z x^-1 y)^5 y^5

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ OVER

x^-4 z^-4

How would I evaluate this if X = 10, y = -3 and z = 3? I would like a step-by-step solution to help me fully understand it.

Comment: Try math.stackexchange.com for this question.

Comment: Hardly - it's simple algebra.  High school stuff.  C'mon!

Comment: @duffymo maybe it is, but it's certainly not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerator evaluates as `(z*y*x^-1)^5 * y^5`

further rewriting `((z^5*y^5)*y^5)/x^5`

Denominator `((1/x^4)*(1/z^4))`

Final Answer would be `((y^10)*(z^9))/x`

as per your values it `(3^19)/10`

Answer (score 1):

Exponentials have higher priority in most computer languages, so adding parentheses like this should make it clearer.  I'm assuming that you're dividing the first polynomial by the second.  It's simple algebra.

```
(z x^-1 y)^5 y^5
---------------- = 
x^-4 z^-4

(y^10)(z^9)/x
```

You substitute the numbers.

Comment: simple algebra, that you got wrong the first time... (edited within 5 minutes so it doesn't actually show)

Comment: Yeah, I'm at work and was going too fast.  Not too hard, though.  My point was it certainly does not need math.overflow.  And I didn't see your answer, so I can't comment on your algebraic skills.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

> ((z * x^-1 * y)^5 * y^5)/(x^-4 * z^-4)

Commute the exponent to the z factor: (A * B)^N => A^N * B^N

> (z^5 * (x^-1 * y)^5 * y^5)/(x^-4 * z^-4)

Commute the exponent to the x and y factors: (A * B)^N => A^N * B^N

> (z^5 * (x^-1)^5 * y^5 * y^5)/(x^-4 * z^-4)

Simplify the exponenet on the x factor: (A^N)^M => A^(N*M)

> (z^5 * x^-5 * y^5 * y^5)/(x^-4 * z^-4)

Combine the y factors: A^N * A^M => A^(N+M)

> (z^5 * x^-5 * y^10)/(x^-4 * z^-4)

Remove the negative exponent on x: 1/A^-N => A^N

> (z^5 * x^-5 * y^10 * x^4) / (z^-4)

Remove the negative exponenet on z:  1/A^-N => A^N

> z^5 * x^-5 * y^10 * x^4 * z^4

Combine the z factors: A^N * A^M => A^(N+M)

> z^9 * x^-5 * y^10 * x^4

Combine the x factors:  A^N * A^M => A^(N+M)

> z^9 * x^-1 * y^10

Remove the negative exponent on x: A^(-N) => 1/A^N

> (z^9 * y^10)/(x^1)

Simplify the x factor: A^1 => A

> (z^9 * y^10)/(x)

And that's the algebraic form of your answer.

Next, subsitute the values:

> 3^9 * (-3)^10 / 10

Factor the exponents:

> (3^3)^3 * (-3)^10 / 10
>
> (3^3)^3 * ((-3)^2)^5 / 10

Evalutate the innermost exponents:

> (3 * 3 * 3)^3 * ((-3)^2)^5 / 10
>
> (9 * 3)^3 * ((-3)^2)^5 / 10
>
> 27^3 * ((-3)^2)^5 / 10
>
> 27^3 * 9^5 / 10

Continue evaluation exponents, breaking them down for simplicity:

> 27 * 27 * 27 * 9^5 / 10
>
> 27 * 27 * 27 * 9^5 / 10
>
> 729 * 27 * 9^5 / 10
>
> 19683 * 9^5 / 10
>
> 19683 * 9^2 * 9^2 * 9 / 10
>
> 19683 * 81 * 81 * 9 / 10

Then multiply the factors:

> 19683 * 81 * 729 / 10
>
> 19683 * 59049 / 10
>
> 1162261467 / 10
>
> 116226146.7

And there's your final answer.

You could also take advantage of the fact that X^N = (-X)^N if N is even by replacing -3 with 3 since 10 is even.

> 3^9 * (-3)^10 / 10
>
> 3^9 * 3^10 / 10
>
> 3^19 / 10
>
> 3 * 3^18 / 10
>
> 3 * (3^9)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * 3^8)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * (3^2)^4)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * ((3^2)^2)^2)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * (9^2)^2)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * 81^2)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (3 * 6561)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * (19683)^2 / 10
>
> 3 * 387420489 / 10
>
> 1162261467 / 10
>
> 116226146.7